# Is there any way to use EntityQuery on entity_reference fields in reverse?

Tags: 9, entities

Let's say I have two custom entity types: entity_one, entity_many.

I know how to use an EntityQuery to find entity_one matches if there is a multi-value entity reference field on entity_one.

```php
$results = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('entity_one`)
    ->getQuery()
    ->condition('field_referencing_many.entity:entity_many.field_string', $value)
    ->execute();
```

but what if there was no `entity_one.field_referencing_many` and instead there was a `entity_many.field_reference_one` that allows each entity_many child entity to reference its parent? Is there any magic in EntityQuery that would allow the tables to be joined and queried with that *reverse* entity_reference field? I still want results from entity_one storage.

Comment: Simply query the field directly in that case ->condition('field_referencing_one', $value) where $value is the entity ID you want references to.

Comment: I don't know the entity_one IDs that I want. That is the point of the query :) I also don't know the entity_many IDs. All I know is entity_many.field_string has a value of $value. (this is obviously a made up example)

Comment: OK so you want to filter on that key and get the related entities (rather than the original entities). I would think this is probably easier to achieve using a SELECT query rather than an entity query, but that doesn't answer your question so hopefully somebody else can,